# How does NetworkX adjacency_matrix() work internally?

Tags: python, graph, networkx, adjacency-matrix

As the title says, I'm working with graphs and using NetworkX. I looked for it but didn't found how the `adjacency_matrix` function works internally. If someone can explain or give me information about it I would appreciate it.

Comment: Why don't you simply look at the source code?

Comment: using `print( networkx.__file__ )` you can find folder with source code. In one of file in folder you can find this function.

Comment: digging in code I found source code in `print( networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.__file__ )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`adjacency_matrix`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html#adjacency-matrix) is basically an alias for [`to_scipy_sparse_matrix`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_scipy_sparse_matrix.html#to-scipy-sparse-matrix) - the source code for which is below - I've added a few comments to what is in the networkx source. Further than that, you'll need to dig into the source code for [`scipy.sparse.coo_matrix`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/coo.py).

```
def to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G, nodelist=None, dtype=None,
                           weight='weight', format='csr'):
    from scipy import sparse

    # Generate nodelist if no nodelist was passed
    if nodelist is None:
        nodelist = list(G)

    # Check the graph has nodes/edges
    nlen = len(nodelist)
    if nlen == 0:
        raise nx.NetworkXError("Graph has no nodes or edges")

    # Check if nodelist has duplicates using a set
    if len(nodelist) != len(set(nodelist)):
        msg = "Ambiguous ordering: `nodelist` contained duplicates."
        raise nx.NetworkXError(msg)

    # Assign arbitrary indexes to each node
    index = dict(zip(nodelist, range(nlen)))

    # Create a zip of weight coefficients for every edge in the graph
    coefficients = zip(*((index[u], index[v], d.get(weight, 1))
                         for u, v, d in G.edges(nodelist, data=True)
                         if u in index and v in index))
    try:
        row, col, data = coefficients
    except ValueError:
        # there is no edge in the subgraph
        row, col, data = [], [], []

    # If G is a directed graph, call sparse.coo_matrix to generate the matrix
    # Otherwise, we need to symmetrise the matrix before calling this function.
    if G.is_directed():
        M = sparse.coo_matrix((data, (row, col)),
                              shape=(nlen, nlen), dtype=dtype)
    else:
        # symmetrize matrix
        d = data + data
        r = row + col
        c = col + row
        # selfloop entries get double counted when symmetrizing
        # so we subtract the data on the diagonal
        selfloops = list(nx.selfloop_edges(G, data=True))
        if selfloops:
            diag_index, diag_data = zip(*((index[u], -d.get(weight, 1))
                                          for u, v, d in selfloops
                                          if u in index and v in index))
            d += diag_data
            r += diag_index
            c += diag_index
        M = sparse.coo_matrix((d, (r, c)), shape=(nlen, nlen), dtype=dtype)
    try:
        return M.asformat(format)
    # From Scipy 1.1.0, asformat will throw a ValueError instead of an
    # AttributeError if the format if not recognized.
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        raise nx.NetworkXError("Unknown sparse matrix format: %s" % format)
```